# Static 3D Touch not showing navigation and tab bar after lunching

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, 3dtouch, uiapplicationshortcutitem

3D Touch is working fine when I press it on the home screen, but not showing the navigation and tab bar, How can I present Navigation and Tab bar using 3D Touch? Don't know how to Override point for customization after application launch.
Grazie Mille

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {    
enum ShortcutIdentifier: String {
    case First
    case Second
    case Third
    case Fourth
    //Initializers
    init?(fullType: String) {
        guard let last = fullType.components(separatedBy: ".").last else { return nil }
        self.init(rawValue: last)
    }
    //Properties
    var type: String {
        return Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)"
    }
}
var window: UIWindow?

/// Saved shortcut item used as a result of an app launch, used later when app is activated.
var launchedShortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem?

func handleShortCutItem(_ shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var handled = false

    // Verify that the provided shortcutItem type is one handled by the application.
    guard ShortcutIdentifier(fullType: shortcutItem.type) != nil else { return false }

    guard let shortCutType = shortcutItem.type as String? else { return false }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vcc = UIViewController()

    switch (shortCutType) {
    case ShortcutIdentifier.First.type:
        vcc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1")
        handled = true
        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.Second.type:
        vcc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2")
        handled = true
        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.Third.type:
        vcc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3")
        handled = true
        break
    case ShortcutIdentifier.Fourth.type:
        vcc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC4")
        handled = true
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    // Display the selected view controller
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vcc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return handled
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let handledShortCutItem = handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

    completionHandler(handledShortCutItem)
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    guard launchedShortcutItem != nil else { return }

    //handleShortCutItem(shortcut)
    launchedShortcutItem = nil
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // If a shortcut was launched, display its information and take the appropriate action
    if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {

        launchedShortcutItem = shortcutItem
    }
    return true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I present Navigation and Tab bar using 3D Touch

The same way you do it during the normal run of your app. You should not be doing some *special* thing in response to the user pressing the shortcut item (i.e. your `self.window?.rootViewController?.present`, which in effect merely puts up a temporary facade); you should be *navigating* to the actual area of your real app that the shortcut item corresponds to.

Comment: Im not sure, what u mean with that, this code is in my AppDelegate swift file, when I accessing with 3D Touch from home screen-its working, but not showing the navigation and tab bar! Do I need to put this code in ViewController?

Comment: It's not a matter of where the code is. It's the whole idea of what you are doing that is wrong. If there is an area of your app that has a navigation controller / tab bar, then your response to the shortcut menu should be to _go to that area of your app_ just as if the user had navigated to it in the normal way — not to put up some special one-time view controller as a presentation.

Comment: I know, that Im doing wrong, its not working! I still don't understand ur point, my shortcutitem is only in info.plist. Do I need to create shortcut inside that area view controller ? It's my first app, i'm just learning !

Comment: Think about how the user would _usually_ navigate to, say, the AddViewController. In your handling of the shortcut, _you_ navigate to it _in the same way_. And so on, for each of the view controllers that has a shortcut. It is a shortcut way to get to _the normal view controller_.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I really need an example to understand how it works!

Comment: You are the one who is not supplying sufficient information. I do not know the architecture of your app (the view controller hierarchy). If you explain how the _user_ gets to the AddViewController, I can explain how _you_ get to the AddViewController (because it's the same way).

Comment: Okay, so let's talk about the AddViewController. Your app's root view controller is the tab view controller. So you switch to its _first_ view controller; that is the navigation controller. The navigation controller's root view controller is the Players view controller. Now you do the push segue to the AddViewController and there you are.